# Extracting numerical values from a string with at most 6 digits with optional 2 digits for decimal

Tags: python, regex

I have a task from which I need to extract values from a text that represent numerical values. However I am interested in extracting values that have at most 6 digits with decimal being optional.

For example, from the below text:

> Total compensation for Mr. XYZ was $5,123,456 and other salary which was $650,000 in fiscal 2018, was determined to be approximately 8.78 times the median annual compensation for all of the firm's other employees, which was approximately $74,000. Some other salaries are 56000.

I need to extract

```
["650,000", "2018", "8.78", "74,000", "56000"]
```

from this.

The regex I am using:

`((\d{1,3})(?:,[0-9]{3}){0,1}|(\d{1,6}))(\.\d{1,2})?`
It is correctly identifying 650,000 and 74,000 but doesn't identify others correctly.

I found [this](https://www.regextester.com/103979) 7 digit money regex and worked around it to make one for 6 digit but wasn't successful. How do I correct my regex?

Comment: Why do you want to extract 2018, 8.78 etc, which are neither money nor 6 digit ? Doesn't that contradict your rule above ?

Comment: @LogicalKip, basically the problem I am trying to solve has many cases where the $ sign may or may not be there. And also I need all values with at most 6 digits.

Comment: @LogicalKip I have edited the problem statement to make things more clear.

Comment: You put 2018 twice in your expected output, is it a typo ?

Comment: Yeah it was. Too many mistakes sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : `(?<![\d,.])(?:\d,?){0,5}\d(?:\.\d+)?(?!,?\d)`

Here's a detailed explanation:

```
(?x) # flag for readable mode, whitespaces and comments are ignored 

# Make sure to not start in the middle of a number, so no digit, comma or dot before the match
(?<![\d,.])

# k-1 digits, with facultative comma between each. Therefore 5,4,3,2 are allowed for the sake of simplicity, be aware of that
(?:\d,?){0,5}

#The kth digit
\d

# Facultative dot and decimal part
(?:\.\d+)?

# Make sure to not stop in the middle of a big number, so no digit after. Comma is allowed, but only for the grammatical comma, so comma+digit is forbidden
(?!,?\d)
```

There could be improvement, but I think it's what you wanted. There might be some cases not handled, tell me if you find some.
Test it here : https://regex101.com/r/Wxi5Sj/2

Comment: Thank you very much! This is giving the output i needed. Sure I will let you know if there are any cases that were not handled by this.

Comment: can this be generalized for at most k digits? Also an explanation would be very helpful because I might need to tinker with this in future to handle values needing different digit counts

Comment: I think you can generalize by changing the 5 (which is k-1, but it doesn't check the decimals, only the left part). I'll edit with a step by step explanation

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
import re
input = "Total compensation for Mr. XYZ was $5,123,456 and other salary which was $650,000 in fiscal 2018, was determined to be approximately 8.78 times the median annual compensation for all of the firm's other employees, which was approximately $74,000. Some other salaries are 56000. "
print(re.findall(r'(?<=\s)\$?\d{0,3}\,?\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{2})?(?!,?\d)', input))
```

Output

```
['$650,000', '2018', '8.78', '$74,000', '56000']
```

Comment: But this is capturing part of that 7 digit currency $5,123,456. I dont want to do anything with those

Comment: Try now, user `print(re.findall(r'(?<=\s)\$?\d{0,3}\,?\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?', input))`

Comment: It is still capturing part of that 7 digit value. Basically it should reject all such values that have more that 6 significant digits. So my output should be
["650,000", "2018", "8.78", "2018", "74,000", "56000"]